# array/list manipulation in Julia

Tags: julia

I am unfamiliar with Julia notation, and coming from python.

In python, my code would look like this:

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = ([3,4, 5], [6,7,8])  # usually retuned by a function call

# then I stack the list:
z = [x, *y]
```

and get:

```
z = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

However, in julia, I am not sure how to use the * trick, I am using a cumbersome method where I defined all the variables:

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = ([3,4, 5], [6,7,8])  # usually retuned by a function call


z = x
z = hcat(z, y[1])
z = hcat(z, y[2])
```

What would be a more efficient way to write this down? Here this example is simple enough, but I am dealing with more xomplex data and doing the hcat like this feel wrond and is time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia you will use `...` to unpack vector instead of `*` used in Python:

```
julia> [x, y...]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 1, 2]
 [3, 4, 5]
 [6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: How do you read this? I usually think of the star in ``[x, *y]`` as meaning something like ``"paste me right here"``, but in Julia the splat comes after the `y` instead of after the `x`, I wonder what would be a verbal description of what the splat does here... Thanks! (I mean ``[x, ...y]`` would be easy to understand or even ``[x...y]``)

Comment: Suppose `y` is an `AbstractVector` having three elements: `y[1]`, `y[2]` and `y[3]`. In that case writing `y...` is a 100% equivalent to writing exactly `y[1], y[2], y[3]`. I read it "upack my `y` here". To test my explanation please try running `[x, y[1], y[2]] == [x, y...]`

Comment: Ah, nice one, thanks Przemyslaw. "Unpack my y here", that works. Now I know I'll remember how to use it without having to search the help! :-)